# Publish error on fresh umbraco install

Tags: visual-studio, umbraco

I'm very new to umbraco and this is my first install so apologies if i ask some pretty beginner questions.

So I've just installed umbraco using nugent. I build the program and then press 'control & F5' to run it.

After Umbraco is installed I went back to my solution explorer in visual studio and made sure to 'include in project' all the new files and folders that were created.

Now I want to deploy this to my IIS server I have sitting on my server. But when I deploy I get the following web.config error

```
Could not open Source file: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\josha\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Umbraco - SecondAttempt\Umbraco - SecondAttempt\Umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config;\umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config'.    Umbraco___SecondAttempt     0
```

I'm not sure If I'm not doing this correctly since I'm so new to this but I followed a few tutorials and didn't think I set up anything incorrectly.

Comment: Not sure if it is a type or not but you have `;\umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config` appended to the path?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what your asking. What do you mean by appended?

Comment: `c:\users\josha\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Umbraco - SecondAttempt\Umbraco - SecondAttempt\Umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config;\umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config' - I don't believe that is a valid file path because of the semi colon. But also the second part of the path is repeated at the end.

Comment: Check if the file \Umbraco\Install\Views\Web.config is missing or not included in the project.

Comment: This blog post explains what's going on  - http://blog.jan.hebnes.dk/2015/07/umbraco-to-azure-msdeploy-error.html

Answer (score 0):

I still had this issue for 7.5 
The solution:

Inside project dir, if the file ProjectName.wpp.targets does not exist, create it. Make sure that the content will include:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
 <PropertyGroup>
 <AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>False</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>  
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The file doesn't even have to be included in the project. That's it.